# Instagram embed gets wrong height

Tags: instagram

When I use the Instagram embed code, it works for single images just fine. But with albums it gets a wrong height:

```
<blockquote class="instagram-media" data-instgrm-captioned data-instgrm-version="7" style=" background:#FFF; border:0; border-radius:3px; box-shadow:0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5),0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15); margin: 1px; max-width:658px; padding:0; width:99.375%; width:-webkit-calc(100% - 2px); width:calc(100% - 2px);"><div style="padding:8px;"> <div style=" background:#F8F8F8; line-height:0; margin-top:40px; padding:50% 0; text-align:center; width:100%;"> <div style=" background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACwAAAAsCAMAAAApWqozAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAFzUkdCAK7OHOkAAAAMUExURczMzPf399fX1+bm5mzY9AMAAADiSURBVDjLvZXbEsMgCES5/P8/t9FuRVCRmU73JWlzosgSIIZURCjo/ad+EQJJB4Hv8BFt+IDpQoCx1wjOSBFhh2XssxEIYn3ulI/6MNReE07UIWJEv8UEOWDS88LY97kqyTliJKKtuYBbruAyVh5wOHiXmpi5we58Ek028czwyuQdLKPG1Bkb4NnM+VeAnfHqn1k4+GPT6uGQcvu2h2OVuIf/gWUFyy8OWEpdyZSa3aVCqpVoVvzZZ2VTnn2wU8qzVjDDetO90GSy9mVLqtgYSy231MxrY6I2gGqjrTY0L8fxCxfCBbhWrsYYAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC); display:block; height:44px; margin:0 auto -44px; position:relative; top:-22px; width:44px;"></div></div> <p style=" margin:8px 0 0 0; padding:0 4px;"> <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BcIMudZgMQ1/" style=" color:#000; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-style:normal; font-weight:normal; line-height:17px; text-decoration:none; word-wrap:break-word;" target="_blank">&#34;Bringen my baby home for christmas&#34; . Kære Weber Julemand @weber.danmark   Vi har bagt en lækker og meget sprød julepizza til dig med vores ynglings Weber Grill.  Velbekomme  . . #WeberWinterGriller #weberDK #webergrill #weber #home #mydaughter #chrismas #denmark #danmark #love #sunset #grill #aarhus #instagood #food #foodlover #pizza #foodporn #santa #jul #winter #vinter #nofilter #pictureoftheday</a></p> <p style=" color:#c9c8cd; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px; margin-bottom:0; margin-top:8px; overflow:hidden; padding:8px 0 7px; text-align:center; text-overflow:ellipsis; white-space:nowrap;">Ein Beitrag geteilt von Familie Adamsen (@familie_adamsen) am <time style=" font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px;" datetime="2017-11-30T17:40:24+00:00">30. Nov 2017 um 9:40 Uhr</time></p></div></blockquote>
<script async defer src="//platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js"></script>
```

Which is just copied from the embed dialogue. See the codepen for an example: 
https://codepen.io/riedemann/full/e5393d7d77c3e5d5bf9ddb5a065ccd5b/

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was going on or a work around? I'm facing this same issue.

Comment: @kingkool68 unfortunately not. I wrote a mail to the support, no reply yet. We used a static fallback now. Which sucks, but well… :/

Comment: Just encountered this issue. Ended up going with really crappy css solution (backed into a max-height on the blockquote element).

Answer (score 0):

I have determined that the issue only happens when the person viewing the embed is logged in to Instagram. It's entirely Instagram's fault. Not much can be done about it.

Comment: This is nonsense.  Issue presents regardless of user being logged in or not to Instagram.

Comment: It happens also in Disguise browser mode (Incognito), so that's not true.